# How can I fix the vb6tmpl.tbl error that always occur every time I run visual basic 6.0

Tags: visual-studio, vb6

I've already reinstall visual basic 6.0 most likely trice but I always got the same error (Visual Basic was not able to start up due to an invalid system configuration. Missing or not registeredVB6TMPL.TBL). How can I fix this or how you can fix this? I currently using Windows 10.

Comment: Mentioning the exact error message as it appears might help if you want help with this.  And probably also adding your Windows versions.

Comment: run it once in elevated privilege (admin)

Answer (score 2):

There is a [Microsoft Support post](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/262976) dealing with this. The gist is you need to uninstall and reinstall to fix a missing or mis-registered type library.

> A missing or mis-registered type library key for VB6.olb would
>   indicate an improper setup of Visual Basic. Microsoft recommends that
>   you uninstall and reinstall Visual Basic.
>
> To ensure proper reinstallation of Visual Basic, uninstall the current
>   product. Then proceed to reinstall Visual Basic from the original
>   installation disks. For additional information, click the article
>   number below to view the article in the Microsoft Knowledge Base:
>
> [248697](https://support.microsoft.com/EN-US/kb/248697) HOWTO: Manually Uninstall Visual Studio with MSDN Library